# What are the IOMMU Groups that come with the kernel 3.6?

Tags: kernel, virtualization

kernel 3.6 comes with a new feature called IOMMU Groups. So what are these groups and how it will serve virtualizarion

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**IOMMU Groups**,are new featurs to kernel 3.6 which improve the isolation of PCI and PCIe devices using I/O virtualisation technologies such as AMD-Vi and Intel's VT-d.

The IOMMU Groups feature is also the basis for the VFIO (Virtual Function I/O) userspace driver framework (1, 2, 3); mainly intended for KVM, this feature is designed to pass through PCI and PCIe devices to guests, allowing them to access these devices at low latency and high data throughput levels, and without any risk to the host.

Details on VFIO are available in the [documentation](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux-2.6.git;a=commitdiff;h=4a5b2a20ec87384eeb19e70991e7e15a00cad87b) and in [this](https://lwn.net/Articles/474088/) article.